# This Lambda OrderBy seems superfluous in my case - is it?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, arraylist

I don't want to have any unnecessary code, but I want to be "safe," too. Empirical observations have shown that the OrderBy below does nothing - the List is already ordered correctly. Can I rely on that being the case, and remove that OrderBy line?

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
List<int> listInts = new List<int>();
using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(selectedFile)) {
    string line;
    int lineNum = 0;
    int Offset = (int)numericUpDownLinesOfContext.Value;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)     {
        lineNum++;
        if (line.Contains(PlatypusToSearchFor)) {
            // This adds the lines before and after that will provide the desired context
            // (N lines from the log file before and after the searched for value)
            hashSet.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(lineNum - Offset, Offset * 2 + 1));
        }
    }
    // Remove any negative numbers, as well as 0, that might have been added 
    // (0, -1, -2, or -3 are all possibilities, but the first line is #1)
    listInts = hashSet.Where(i => i >= 1).ToList();
    // They seem to be ordered correctly already, but this is just in case:
    listInts = listInts.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Just to add, the ToList call in the Where line is superflous. `hashSet.Where(...).OrderBy(...).ToList()` works fine.

Comment: The `List<int> listInts = new List<int>();` line also does not do anything. The `ToList()` will create the list. Are you sure you need a list by the way? Cant you work with the Set directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you shouldn't remove the `OrderBy`.  `HashSet` does not guarantee any particular ordering.  You may get lucky in testing, but you can't guarantee it will order things the way you expect it to.

From the MSDN documentation on `HashSet` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

> A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and **whose
>   elements are in no particular order**.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 3):

As already stated `HashSet` does not have any particular order. You could use a [`SortedSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) instead if you need that behavior, and you would then not need the `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 2):

A `UnionWith` operation will not preserve ordering.  However you don't have to use the `OrderBy` line either, because .NET provides [a `SortedSet<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) that exposes set operations and automatic sorting behavior.